# Grails 2.x loggers conflict (slf4j, log4j and commons-logging)

Tags: grails, log4j, slf4j

After upgrading existing app from Grails 1.3.7 to Grails 2.0.4 (tried 2.0.3 also) I got some kind of `slf4j` and `log4j` conflict. Seems that

- log4j tries to write to using commons-logging
- commons-logging write to slf4j
- but slf4j logger appender uses log4j

Circular reference. And `java.lang.StackOverflowError` as a result.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.format(PatternLayout.java:500)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter.logMessage(GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter.java:191)
    at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter.error(GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter.java:166)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog.error(SLF4JLog.java:213)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter.logMessage(GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter.java:191)
    at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter.error(GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter.java:166)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog.error(SLF4JLog.java:213)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter.logMessage(GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter.java:191)
    at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter.error(GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter.java:166)
    ...
```

Seems that log4j logs to commons-logging, commons-loggin

I tried to exclude log4j from dependencies, and use `log4j-over-slf4j` as a replaicement but some Grails classes have direct Log4J usage:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/LogManager
    at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:253)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
```

And I can't exclude slf4j, because it's used by standard Grails plugins, like Resources plugin.

Btw, I never had such situation before, with other Grails 2.0.3 projects. Seems that it's something with configuration or dependencies specific only for current application, but I can't find anything unusual.

Anyone had same issue?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by uncommenting default appender:

```
appenders {
    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
}
```

Working now, but it's weird

Answer (score 0):

I had the same `StackOverflowError` . It occurred when Grails tried to log a quite different exception during the start of my application. So the problem has something to do with Grails logging exceptions.

I fixed it by **commenting out** this line in my log4j configuration (in `Config.groovy`):

```
error stdout: "StackTrace"
```

After that the `StackOverflowError` disappeared and I could see the underlying exception.